# About block alignment in heap memory

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, heap-memory

I 'm studying on school assignment which make *malloc()* function realization. I have a question about block alignment.

Is it possible that freed block is not multiple of 8 bytes?

When I saw the code in System Programming textbook about Implicit list realization, It seems that code only consider alignment of allocated block.
I'm very curious about above question.

Comment: `malloc` returns  an address multiple of 8 on 64 bits systems, on the other hand, `free(malloc(n) + something_different_to_0)` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Oh I understand

Answer (score 1):

In GLIBC's allocator, the internal alignment of the blocks is "2 x sizeof(size_t)". On 32-bit systems, *size_t* is 4 bytes. On 64-bit systems, *size_t* is 8 bytes. So, the alignment is respectively 8 and 16 bytes.

**N.B.**: If you need other alignments, the service provides [posix_memalign()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3p.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are only allowed to `free` a memory block that was allocated via `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

If you ensure that those functions always provide an address that is aligned to multiple of 8 bytes, then you do not need to care about `free`ing anything else than such an address. Whoever would try to free an unanligned address would violate the above rule and causing undefined behaviour.